# Changing pagination list class

Tags: pagination, paginate-links

`paginate_links()` function returns unordered list with class named "page-numbers". How can I change this class?

EDIT

Currently, I am using the band-aid method below.

```
$return = paginate_links( $arg );
echo str_replace( "<ul class='page-numbers'>", '<ul class="pagination">', $return );
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: I've found a quick tutorial on this, and what i can se you use the bootstrap theme class so i'll think this will help! [http://www.ordinarycoder.com/paginate_links-class-ul-li-bootstrap/](http://www.ordinarycoder.com/paginate_links-class-ul-li-bootstrap/)

Comment: I have made a php class that is useful when you need to set the LI and A html tags class names. https://gist.github.com/pixeline/1dc662b756c553eb5efcb6ec4753375f

Comment: @ErikLarsson Link is broken.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`paginate_links()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) doesn't offer a parameter and there are no hooks - see [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/general-template.php#L3160) - available to change the class(es). Which means you can do it like you have done it or you create your own pagination function based on `paginate_links()`.

Answer (score 18):

I was also searching for the same solution to use it with bootstrap pagination links,

the below code is working 100% in my theme.

```
function bittersweet_pagination() {

global $wp_query;

if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 ) return; 

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

$pages = paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'type'  => 'array',
    ) );
    if( is_array( $pages ) ) {
        $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') == 0 ) ? 1 : get_query_var('paged');
        echo '<div class="pagination-wrap"><ul class="pagination">';
        foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
                echo "<li>$page</li>";
        }
       echo '</ul></div>';
        }
}
```

use the function to call in index.php e.g; `<?php bittersweet_pagination(); ?>` or any other file. I also overwrite some bootstrap styling it might help you.

```
.pagination-wrap {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
.pagination-wrap .pagination {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}
.pagination-wrap .pagination > li:first-child > a, 
.pagination-wrap .pagination > li:first-child > span {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
}
.pagination-wrap .pagination > li:last-child > a, 
.pagination-wrap .pagination > li:last-child > span {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
}
.pagination-wrap .pagination > li > a,
.pagination-wrap .pagination > li > span {
    background-color: #4FBEBA;
    border: 1px solid #1BA5A0;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.pagination-wrap .pagination > li > a:hover, 
.pagination-wrap .pagination > li > span:hover, 
.pagination-wrap .pagination > li > a:focus, 
.pagination-wrap .pagination > li > span:focus {
    background-color: #1BA5A0;
    border-color: #189690;
}
.pagination-wrap .pagination .current {
    background-color: #1BA5A0;
    border-color: #189690;
}
.pagination-wrap .pagination .current:hover,
.pagination-wrap .pagination .current span:hover {
    background-color: #189690;
    border-color: #148781;
}
```

Comment: You could improve a tad the performance, since this query will be called each time each page is generated, even when no pagination is necessary. add: ``` if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 ) return; ``` after your global $wp_query at the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 8):

for this you need to use type parameter

```
$links = paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $posts_array->max_num_pages,
    'prev_text'          => __( 'Previous page', 'twentyfifteen' ),
    'next_text'          => __( 'Next page', 'twentyfifteen' ),
    'type' => 'list'
) );
   echo $links
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option not noted here is to copy the styles over to the WordPress pagination classes, instead of changing the class assigned to the element.

If you are using Bootstrap and bundling everything with sass, then you can apply the styles easily using the `@extend` directive.

```
ul.page-numbers {
    @extend .pagination;
    > li {
        > a, > span {
            &.page-numbers {
                @extend .page-link
                &:focus, :hover {
                    /* Additional hover/focus styles here */
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This may be pertinent to some situations, but I feel the code in the original question is the best solution for most applications.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just string replace your way to the bootstrap promised land then heres something that may help you.

```
function bootstrap_pagination()
{
    global $wp_query;
    $big = 999999999;
    $listString = paginate_links(array(
        'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big)),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'prev_text'    => __('← Previous'),
        'next_text'    => __('Next  →'),
        'type'  => 'list',

    ));
    
    $listString = str_replace("<ul class='page-numbers'>", '<ul class="pagination">', $listString);
    $listString = str_replace('page-numbers', 'page-link', $listString);
    $listString = str_replace('<li>', '<li class="page-item">', $listString);
    $listString = str_replace(
        '<li class="page-item"><span aria-current="page" class="page-link current">',
        '<li class="page-item active"><span aria-current="page" class="page-link">',
        $listString
    );


    echo $listString;

}
```